# What is the name of the function that results in a graphic that slowly rises and suddenly spikes up?

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm looking for a proper word or words that would describe a function that would start at zero, gradually climb toward one and then abruptly curve into the infinity.

Like on the attached graph?[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It has a vertical asymptote

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you! I googled "vertical asymptote" just now and it seems to be somewhat different from what I'm looking for: https://www.purplemath.com/modules/asymtote.htm Namely, it seems to be the opposite. What I need is something that's on the positive side of the graph, crawling near zero for a while and then abruptly curving upward...

Comment: Your graph looks like $y=\dfrac1 {x^2}$; a function could be positive or negative to the left of a vertical asymptote; cf. $y=\dfrac{-1}x$ and $y=\dfrac1x$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Is there a name for it? Something like "cubical parabola" etc. Let me explain why I ask. I'm trying to find a clear mathematical description of the graph that would illustrate a sudden spike in a dramatic conflict in traditional Chinese storytelling...

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Changed my illustration to ask question in a less incoherent way. Could you please take a look?

Comment: $y=\dfrac1x$ is a hyperbola

Comment: Why do you need a clear mathematical description for a purely figurative analogy? You could just say "exponentially rising" and then people won't have to crack open a math textbook just to figure out what you're trying to say about literature.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner a hyperbola is slightly closer, for example this one: https://www.geogebra.org/m/aStXWPwb – but it seems inverted. What would be non-inverted version?

Comment: @Rahul Thank you. The "why" is because explaining something with a clear math example is often the easiest. "Exponentially rising" could mean all kinds of things. but what I need to show is the dynamic not rising at all... until suddenly it abruptly curves up. Just like on the graph I posted. Surely there has to be a function that does just that?

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov:  you mean like $y=\dfrac{-1}x$ ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I think this may be the one. But I'm trying to run it here and it wouldn't show me the graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/  Could you help me please? What would it look like?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I was able to check, and it places the curves differently from the graph I used. What I need is to place the curve in the positive: + x and + y... Sorry for torturing you with this! ;-)

Comment: Did you try $y=\dfrac1{x^2}$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Same effect: the mirror image of what I'm looking for. :-(